# PuTTY sending extra characters at the beginning of TELNET connection initialisation

Tags: telnet, putty

When a TELNET session is initialised using PuTTY, I see that PuTTY is sending the following characters to the server at the beginning of the connection:

`..... .....'.........`

I was able to capture this using WireShark.
The hex characters are as follows:

`ff fb 1f ff fb 20 ff fb 18 ff fb 27 ff fd 01 ff fb 03 ff fd 03`

Can you please help me understand why PuTTY sends these characters?
I assumed it is something with the connection, but then, these characters are found in the **DATA** category of the WireShark capture.

Here is a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGZru4KPmsM

Comment: Those look like standard telnet option negotiating sequences. You should probably spend more time to read about [telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) and the protocol specifications.

Comment: If these are standard telnet negotiating sequences, why does it not appear when telnet is initialised using other tools like zoc terminal, etc.? Why does this happen only with PuTTY?

Comment: Perhaps there's settings in the other client to not start with sending these option negotiating sequences? Or perhaps PuTTY is more telnet-compliant than the other clients? There are unfortunately many so-called "telnet clients" which only handles sending plain text and just don't care about the rich telnet protocol.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) and [Elmi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1138160/elmi).

These extra chunk of characters are the negotiation sequences from PuTTY (client) to the server.
Negotiations allow the client to have an enriched experience.
A list of negotiation sequences in telnet protocol and their explanation is given [here](http://mud-dev.wikidot.com/telnet:negotiation)

If you are using PuTTY and do not need these sequences, go to
`Connection > Telnet`
and set the `Telnet negotiation mode` to `Passive`

Here is a link to [Elmi's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908008/telnet-session-starts-with-21-bytes-of-crap?rq=1)